# Which one of the registers are being returned?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I tried writing an assembly progam that does an input number power of 4. It'll loop and multiply %eax current value with the original input number until it jumps to done when %ecx value is 0.

But it's returning 0 after the program run. I'm not sure why(?), does the %ecx registers value get returned instead of the %eax?

What are the rules regarding what gets returned when there are multiple registers in play with values in them?

```
.globl funk
.globl _funk
funk:
_funk:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %edx
movl $1, %eax
movl $4, %ecx
jmp check

check:
cmpl $0, %ecx
jz done
jmp multiply

done:
popl %ebp
ret

multiply:
mull %edx
dec %ecx
jmp check
```

Comment: `mull %edx` overwrites `EDX` with the upper 32-bit value of the 64-bit result which is probably 0. The next multiplication is: `EAX`* 0 -> 0. No matter what follows, `EAX` stays 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In assembly language, *every* register's value gets returned. In other words, when you `ret`urn from a procedure, nothing changes with regards to the registers.** All the values will be exactly as you left them before reaching the `ret` statement. The caller of the procedure will see everything just as it was. In this respect, you can think of the `ret` working just like a `jmp` back to the caller. (In fact, it is a lot like this—it pops the address of the caller off the stack, and then jumps back to it.)

That means that, if you want to "return" a value, the caller and callee need to agree on where that value is going to be returned. Since you're programming in assembly, you (the programmer) get to pick for yourself. Nothing is pre-determined. You could decide to "return" the value in `EAX`, or in `ECX`, or in a different register, or different values in *multiple* registers, or even "return" the value in memory (i.e., on the stack).

Now, what you are probably thinking of is when you interoperate with C or C++ code. In these languages, there is typically a standardized *calling convention* (actually determined by the ABI, not the language, but let's not split hairs). On x86, all C/C++ calling conventions that I'm aware of return integer-sized values in the `EAX` register. As such, this isn't a bad convention to adopt for yourself when writing your own assembly code. But do be aware that it is just a convention, and it is possible to do different things for greater flexibility. *Always* check the documentation for a particular assembly-language procedure to see how it (A) expects to get its inputs (parameters), (B) where/how it returns its values (if any), and (C) what registers (if any) it clobbers. None of these things are a given. They are all defined by the calling convention in C/C++ code, which doesn't exist when you're writing assembly, so you get to make up your own.

---

Now then, let's look at your actual code.

This instruction:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %edx
```

suggests that your `funk` instruction expects to be passed a DWORD-sized value on the stack. As you just learned, that expectation should really have been documented in a comment preceding this function's definition.

In this code:

```
movl $4, %ecx
jmp check

check:
cmpl $0, %ecx
```

the `jmp check` is pointless. `check` is the very next label. If you don't `jmp` there, execution is going to fall through to there *anyway*, so you might as well skip the jump. This will make your code simpler and faster.

This:

```
cmpl $0, %ecx
```

is an inefficient way to test whether a register is 0. It works, of course, but it isn't as good as `testl %ecx, %ecx`. In other words, bitwise-AND the register with itself (`TEST`), which will set exactly the same flags as a subtraction (`CMP`), but will do so more quickly and require fewer instruction bytes. Just a little optimization tip. You'll still use `cmp $0, xxx` to see if a *memory* location is 0, though, since you can't do `test mem, mem`. (Both operands can't be memory locations.)

**The *real* problem with your code is this instruction:**

```
mull %edx
```

This is a 32-bit multiplication, which means that it is doing `EDX:EAX = EAX * EDX`. In other words, it's multiplying the current contents of `EAX` by the operand to `MUL` (`EDX`), and storing the results in `EDX:EAX`. That colon notation just means that the high-order DWORD of the result is stored in `EDX`, and the low-order DWORD of the result is stored in `EAX`. Once you see that, two things should be obvious: (1) a 32-bit multiplication produces a *64-bit result*, and (2) it is clobbering both the `EAX` and `EDX` registers. Well, now the problem should be obvious: your next multiplication will be `EAX * EDX`, but `EDX` is 0, so the result will always be 0. That's why it's returning 0. In fact, at the end of your `funk` function, `EAX`, `EDX`, and `ECX` will *all* be 0!

---

**Let's rewrite the code to fix these problems, and re-organize it to make it a bit easier to read:**

```
# Computes input to the 4th power.
# 
# Parameters: The input is a DWORD-sized value passed on the stack.
# Returns:    EAX contains the result
# Clobbers:   EAX, ECX, EDX
funk:
    # (You used to set up a stack frame here, but you don't really need that,
    #  so I'm going to skip doing it altogether.)

    # Initialize our other registers.
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $4, %ecx

    # See if we've done enough multiplications, or should keep looping.
check:
    testl %ecx, %ecx
    jz    done

    # Multiply EAX by the parameter (found at an offset of 4 from the stack pointer).
    mull 4(%esp)

    # Decrement our counter and loop again.
    decl %ecx
    jmp  check

done:
    # (We didn't create a stack frame, so we don't need to tear it down.)
    # Just return, with the result still in EAX.
    ret
```

The way I wrote this, I reload the multiplicand from the stack each time. I guess that's kind of inefficient, but so is doing multiplication in a loop! If you wanted to, you could use another register (say, `EBX`) to hold the multiplicand. There are lots of different ways to write the same code.

---

Another possible optimization would be to rearrange the code so that `check` was at the bottom of the loop and you could piggy-back off of the flags set by the `DEC` instruction, rather than having to do an extra `TEST`/`CMP`. (This might not always work. It works only when you *know* that you want to loop *at least once*—the difference between a `do`…`while` loop and a `while` loop in C.)

Also, in this version, we won't clobber anything, which will make it easier on the caller. For any registers that we need to use, we'll preserve their contents by `push`ing them at the top of the function and `pop`ping them at the bottom.

(Now, this is where you generally would be taught to create a stack frame and use fixed offsets from the `EBP` register, but that isn't strictly necessary, and isn't how a C compiler would do it. It would just figure out that you're pushing 3 DWORD-sized values on the stack, so that's going to decrement the stack pointer by 3×4 = 12, so the parameter that used to be found at an offset of 4 is now going to be found at an offset of 16.)

```
# Computes input to the 4th power in a slightly more efficient way.
# 
# Parameters: The input is a DWORD-sized value passed on the stack.
# Returns:    EAX contains the result
# Clobbers:   <none>
funk:
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl %edx

    movl 16(%esp), %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $4, %ecx

    mull %ebx
    decl %ecx
    jnz  check

    popl %edx
    popl %ecx
    popl %ebx
    ret
```

---

Before I end this diatribe, I want to call your attention to a subtle bug. It goes back to something that I mentioned earlier, about a 32-bit multiplication returning a 64-bit value. The reason it does that is because **it is possible for two 32-bit values multiplied together to *overflow* a 32-bit value**. This is even *more* likely when you do an exponentiation operation. So, if you want to protect yourself against overflow, and support relatively large input values, you need to return a 64-bit result.

The way that a C compiler would typically do that would be to return with the result in `EDX:EAX`, just like the `MUL` instruction does. Although you could do it any way you wanted, this is a good convention to follow.

Let's go all-out on efficiency this time. The power to be computed (4) is a constant, so we can dispense with the loop altogether.

```
; Computes input to 4th power, without risking an overflow in the result.
; Parameters: EAX contains the input
; Returns:    EDX:EAX contains the result
; Clobbers:   ECX
FunkyFunk:
    mull   %eax            # EDX:EAX = EAX * EAX
    movl   %edx, %ecx
    imull  %eax, %ecx      # ECX = EAX * EDX
    mull   %eax            # EDX:EAX = EAX * EAX
    addl   %ecx, %edx      # EDX = ECX + EDX
    addl   %ecx, %edx      # EDX = ECX + EDX
    ret
```

By the way, why did you name this function `funk`? Why didn't you name it `pow4` or something obvious like that? Programming is hard enough already, don't make it *harder* on yourself and others who have to read your code!

Comment: Note that your first sentence isn't universally true. For example, on windowed architectures like SPARC, only some registers are actually returned.

Comment: Very little of what you write in an answer about x86 assembly is true on other architectures. It is a weirdo. That's why tags are so important.